# Core Data & iCloud Error: Unable to find relationship destination object

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I´ve been using Core Data and iCloud for a while in my app now. But its suddenly acting up like crazy. The problem is when a device should import new changes from iCloud i.e in the

```
- (void)persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
```

If I add 1 new entity on **device A** the entity will sync over to **device B**. But if I add multiple new entities at the same time only the one or two last will sync over to **device B**. This is when I get the error message:

```
Unable to find relationship destination object:
[_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation processObjects:withState:andImportContext:outError:](1017): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x14694540>{name = '(null)'}
```

I am also printing whats about to change (the [notification userInfo]) and it looks like this when following that error message.

```
{
    deleted = "{(\n)}";
    inserted = "{(\n)}";
    updated = "{(\n)}";
}
```

**My model:**

I have a **Company** that has **Employees**. No one of them has any delete rule in the .xcdatamodel. It is the **Employees** who is raising `Unable to find relationship destination object:`
I seem to get some **Employees** with **Company** "null/nil"

This is how I retrieve my MOC:

```
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {

        return managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
        // Could this result in stuff?
        [managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];

        [managedObjectContext setStalenessInterval:0.0];

    }
    return managedObjectContext;
```

And this is how I save to the MOC

```
    [context performBlockAndWait:^{
        success = [context save:&error];
    }];
```

My question is, have anyone else experienced this problem? How do I go about solving it? Any ideas that is moving me in the right direction is really appreciated. Put a comment if you want me to include more information about my problem.

**UPDATE:**
I filed a bug report and this problem seems to be fixed in iOS9 b5.

Comment: I have something similar and mainly it happens when I delete the object in relationship. I've been thinking that merge policy can be a problem.

Comment: Ok I Will look into my merge policy. I'll get back to you if I make any progress

Comment: I´ve been experimenting with merge policies for a while now but it doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: I gave up on iCloud integration as I experienced lots of very strange bugs, schema conflicts and many other things that can just break sync in my app forever. I am looking into Ensembles framework, which seems to work better.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will check that out, hope this thread will be alive for some time though. Would really appreciate some hints. Cheers man

Comment: Not sure the version you are using but I ran into some issues with the new beta's where my apps would fail to sync with similar errors.  I logged a bug which Apple have acknowledge.  This has been a long time intermittent issue and I have implemented some fixes in my apps.  Basically this involves removing the store from iCloud and then sharing it via iCloud again - usually this fixes the problem for a while.  I find this seems to happen if I have used the app for some time but have not allowed the devices to sync.  This seems to result in some inconsistencies in the data.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Thanks for sharing your experience! 
I used a DTS for this issue and got a reply yesterday when they said "no known workaround at this time" so I also filed a bug report. We´ve had problems with iCloud for some time now, the strange thing about this problem I am experiencing now is that it doesn't get solved with clean install+remove iCloud from settings. Do you mind sharing how you are going about removing the store and uploading it again? Thanks again.

Comment: Check this site out for the sample apps and the most recent Swift version of the Core Data stack manager I am using.  http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/.  The basic process is to migrate the iCloud store to a local store, to remove the iCloud store using the Core Data API to do so and then after removing the app from all other devices migrate the local store back to iCloud.  The core data stack manager has functions for doing all of the above.  Check the sample apps for usage...

Comment: Finally for your testing use a terminal to delete all files from the ubiquity container to check if this fixes things, you may have to implement a function in your app for the user to do the same.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald The problem seems to be fixed in iOS9 b5

Comment: Nope I still have sync getting stuck on the latest build.

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the same issue on iOS 9.2